# Transformar código em Ajax Jquery para Javascript Puro

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, paginação

Olá, pessoal tudo bem? Eu estou criando um sistema de paginação. Entretanto, o sistema de paginação é o único sistema do site que está utilizando Jquery. Ou seja, está carregando uma biblioteca inteira, afetando o tempo de carregamento do site (SEO).

**O código em Ajax:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.load-more').click(function(){
        var row = Number($('#row').val());
        var allcount = Number($('#all').val());
        var rowperpage = 6;
        row = row + rowperpage;

        if(row <= allcount){
            $("#row").val(row);

            $.ajax({
                url: 'getData.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {row:row},
                beforeSend:function(){
                    $(".load-more").text("Carregando...");
                },
                success: function(response){
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $(".post:last").after(response).show().fadeIn("slow");
                        var rowno = row + rowperpage;
                        if(rowno > allcount){
                            $(".load-more").prop('disabled', true);
                            $('.load-more').css("background","grey");
                        }else{
                            $(".load-more").text("Carregar Mais");
                        }
                    }, 2000);

                }
            });
        } }); });
```

Eu tentei recriar o código, porém não está funcionando. De acordo com o identificador de erros do Chrome, não há problemas no código. Alguém tem alguma ideia do que seja?

**O código em JS Puro recriado (não funcionando):**

```
function myFunction(){
    var row = document.getElementById('row').value;
    var allcount = document.getElementById('all').value;
    var rowperpage = 6;
    row = row + rowperpage;

if(row <= allcount){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', 'getData.php', true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        row = document.getElementById('row').value;
        document.getElementsByClassName("post");
        var rowno = row + rowperpage;
        if(rowno > allcount){
            document.getElementById("load-more").disabled = true;
        } else { }
        };
      request.onerror = function() {
      };
    request.send(row);
  }
}
```

Fico muito agradecido.

Comment: mas ao menos faz o request, chega na pagia php? olho na ferramenta de dev do navegador, na aba de rede, se fez o request e teve resposta?

Comment: @RicardoPontual sim

Comment: se teve resposta tem de cair na function atribuida ao `onreadystatechange`. Veja o que tem em `request.response` (coloque uma linha logo após o `request.onreadystatechange = function() {`)